# Vue: lost object attribute after put response.data to local aray

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have API that returns json objects like this:

```
[
{"id":3,"delivery_from":"bsl","task_id":410169,"unit_job_id":224128,"completed_at":null,"deleted_at":null,"created_at":"2021-10-20T13:24:07.000000Z"},
{"id":3,"delivery_from":"bsl","task_id":410169,"unit_job_id":224128,"completed_at":null,"deleted_at":null,"created_at":"2021-10-20T13:24:07.000000Z"}
]
```

When i print response.data in browser console, I see that all objects params are ok, but when I put response.data to local array deliveryJobs: [], then I see that task_id attribute is undefined. What wrong I am doing?

```
<script>
  import AxiosHandler from './mixins/AxiosHandler'
  import axios from 'axios'

  export default {
    i18n: window.i18n,
    mixins: [
      AxiosHandler,
    ],
    props: {
      unitJobId: Number,
      unitId: Number,
      taskId: Number
    },
    data: () => ({
      deliveryJobs: [],
      unitJob: {}
    }),
    async created () {
      this.getDeliveryJobs()
    },
    methods: {
      getDeliveryJobs () {
        axios
        .get(`/api/v1/unitjobdelivery`, { params : { unit_job_id : this.unitJobId } })
        .then(response => {
          this.deliveryJobs = response.data
        })
        .catch(this.handleAxiosError)
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

[image: Undefined task_id]

Comment: So `deliveryJobs` is local in this component, but `taskId` received as a prop. Are you shure you don´t mutate it anywhere? As `vue.js` properties are reactive, there has to be some action that cause `task_id` in your object getting undefined.

Comment: Hi Stiven, maybe i don't understand what exactly you mean, but don't think it is due to the prop taskId. I removed prop and result is the same -  task_id exist in the response.data, but it dissapears when I give response.data to deliveryJobs []

Comment: What I mean is, that there has to be some point where you mutate `task_id`, as it wouldn´t be possible that it changes from a number to undefined without any action.

Comment: I don't see that point what you mean, I have no idea what makes object property undefined

Answer (score 0):

Solution found.
My API was returning laravel collection instead of array. I changed return to array and now all works fine.